# How to generate comment inside a method with JCodeModel

Tags: jcodemodel

I need something like this

```
public void method() {
    //TODO generated sources
}
```

Here is how I generate a class and a method

```
JCodeModel cm = new JCodeModel();
JDefinedClass dc = cm._class("MyClass");
JMethod method = dc.method(JMod.PUBLIC, cm.VOID,"method");
```

Answer (score 6):

adding `method.body().directStatement("//TODO generated sources");` worked